# iframe onload event

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iframe onload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975526/iframe-onload-event)

I've a simple piece of code:

```
<script>
function change(){document.getElementById("browse").src = document.getElementById("addr").value;}
function update(){document.getElementById("addr").value = document.getElementById("browse").src;}
<script>
<input type="text" id="addr"><input type="button" value="Go" onclick="change();">
<iframe id="browse" style="width:100%;height:100%" onload="update();"></iframe>
```

update(); is not called when e.g. link inside the iframe was clicked and new page loaded.

What's the problem?