# Catch error if iframe src fails to load . Error :-"Refused to display 'http://www.google.co.in/' in a frame.."

Tags: jquery, iframe, knockout.js, same-origin-policy

I am using `Knockout.js` to bind iframe `src` tag(This will be configurable with respect to  User).

Now, if user has configured http://www.google.com (I know it won't load in iframe, thats why I am using it for -ve scenario) and that has to be shown in IFrame.
but it throws error:-

> Refused to display 'http://www.google.co.in/' in a frame because it
>   set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

I have the following code for Iframe:-

```
<iframe class="iframe" id="iframe" data-bind="attr: {src: externalAppUrl, height: iframeheight}">
    <p>Hi, This website does not supports IFrame</p>
</iframe>
```

What I want is, if the URL fails to load. I want to display **Custom Message**.
[image: Screenshot of console when I get error]
[**FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/ALBXR/)

Now, if I use onload and onerror as:-

```
<iframe id="browse" style="width:100%;height:100%" onload="alert('Done')" onerror="alert('Failed')"></iframe>
```

It works fine loading w3schools.com but not with google.com.

Secondly:- if I make it as a function and try like I have done in my fiddle, it doesn't works.

```
<iframe id="browse" style="width:100%;height:100%" onload="load" onerror="error"></iframe>
```

I don't know how should I make it run and capture the error.

Edited:- I have seen [Want to call a function if iframe doesn't load or load's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534001/want-to-call-a-function-if-iframe-doesnt-load-or-loads/9576180#9576180) question in stackoverflow but it shows error for sites that can be loaded in iframe.

Also, I have looked into [Stackoverflow iframe on load event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975526/iframe-onload-event/5975562#5975562)
Thanks!!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You wont be able to do this from the client side because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) set by the browsers.  You wont be able to get much information from the iFrame other than basic properties like its width and height.

Also, google sets in its response header an '[X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)' of SAMEORIGIN.

Even if you did an ajax call to google you wont be able to inspect the response because the browser enforcing Same Origin Policy.

So, the only option is to make the request from your server to see if you can display the site in your IFrame.

So, on your server.. your web app would make a request to www.google.com and then inspect the response to see if it has a header argument of X-Frame-Options.  If it does exist then you know the IFrame will error.

Comment: Roblox uses an `iframe` trick to detect if the game is installed using `<iframe src="roblox-player:foo">` by detecting a custom URI handler.  Detecting this `iframe` failure triggers the "Download" button to appear.  How do they do it then?

Comment: @QZ Support I have no idea what your talking about.

Comment: @EvanLarsen I'm mentioning a very popular video game that successfully uses the `<iframe>` technique to launch (and I was hoping detect) a URI handler registered in the OS.  It's a free game, you can install it and see for yourself.  When you join a game through the browser, it uses an iframe hack to launch the game.  If it fails, they show the "download" button.  Somehow they know whether or not the URI was handled properly.  My initial guess was catching the `iframe` error, but the answers (as well as my tests) seem to suggest that it's not possible.  How do they know when the iframe fails?

Comment: This is just a guess but I bet the website is just calling a self hosted web app on your local machine. If the call fails then it shows the download button. Once you download and install the game on your machine then the website will be able to call the local self hosted web app.  By self hosted web app.. I mean just an app with http end points which can be called by any website which knows about it.  (ie. https://localhost:7845/opengame/room/2534 )

Comment: The `localhost:7845` is quite the assumption.   First, it will hit mixed content warnings/errors (roblox.com uses HTTPS) and next, it would need failover ports in case of conflicts.  The technique used to launch the software is an `iframe`.  This can be observed by examining the page source.  Somehow when this fails to launch the software, they're able to detect it.  This may be done through a "phone home" + timeout method using the browser tracker ID.  I mention this because this `iframe` failure detection is useful for launching associated apps, but only if the failure can be detected.

Comment: When installing software on your machine they could also install x509 certificates in your trusted certificates store which allows HTTPS and also configure failover ports in case of conflicts. Lots of software is built this way. The iframe method seems like a convoluted way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 16):

I think that you can bind the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event of the iframe, the event fires when the iframe content is fully loaded.

At the same time you can start a setTimeout, if the iFrame is loaded clear the timeout alternatively let the timeout fire.

Code:

```
var iframeError;

function change() {
    var url = $("#addr").val();
    $("#browse").attr("src", url);
    iframeError = setTimeout(error, 5000);
}

function load(e) {
    alert(e);
}

function error() {
    alert('error');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#browse').on('load', (function () {
        load('ok');
        clearTimeout(iframeError);
    }));

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/QXc6P/

### Second problem

It is because you miss the parens in the inline function call; try change this:

```
<iframe id="browse" style="width:100%;height:100%" onload="load" onerror="error"></iframe>
```

into this:

```
<iframe id="browse" style="width:100%;height:100%" onload="load('Done func');" onerror="error('failed function');"></iframe>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ALBXR/4/

Comment: Hey, just looked at the fiddle - it's never throwing an error.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and Chrome - no matter what url I put into the textbox it says "done" and "done func" :(

Comment: Try using the first fiddle link not the second

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward : both fiddle link is not working ... it is not opening ... have you deleted the fiddle ?

Comment: minus 1 because as comments above state: the fiddle never throws the expected error message when iframe fails to load. this is because load event of iframe fires even when it does not load the content.

Comment: Doesn't catch the exception for the iframe tag.. Is that working code?

Comment: This should not be the selected answer.  The one by Evan below is correct: the browser security prevents detecting this.

Comment: `settimeout` while we like to get the error message... -1

Comment: Not sure if this worked at some point. But not working anymore. The `load` seems to be firing irrespective of failure or not. Error does not fire despite developer tools showing the following message - `Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`. [Server side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22071412/433390) validation may be the only option.

Comment: onerror no longer triggering from this fiddle. Just getting a "done" event in either case.

Answer (score 9):

The onload will always be trigger, i slove this problem use try catch block.It will throw an exception when you try to get the contentDocument.

```
iframe.onload = function(){
   var that = $(this)[0];
   try{
        that.contentDocument;
   }
   catch(err){
        //TODO 
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest way I've come across so far and it actually works too!

Comment: This also doesn't work for cross domains - it'll throw an error either way

Comment: This worked for me, for my own domain's iframe. X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Comment: for me it throws the same exception even when the iframe loaded the content. how do you know if the content is not loaded?

Comment: I was about to answer that it's possible to catch that error in this way! But you already did! 
I'm handling the same exact issue (and also to check if the user was redirected to a certain page in my domain) in this way!
I came across this question searching for "handling errors in iframe", but I'm now facing a 503 error inside an iframe!

Answer (score 8):

This is a slight modification to Edens answer - which for me in chrome didn't catch the error. Although you'll still get an error in the console:
"Refused to display 'https://www.google.ca/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'." At least this will catch the error message and then you can deal with it.

```
 <iframe id="myframe" src="https://google.ca"></iframe>

 <script>
 myframe.onload = function(){
 var that = document.getElementById('myframe');

 try{
    (that.contentWindow||that.contentDocument).location.href;
 }
 catch(err){
    //err:SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://*********" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    console.log('err:'+err);
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: This results in "cannot read property 'location' of null" error for `that.contentDocument` and many working sites will still throw an error on `that.contentWindow` during the loading process.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it with `window.length`. 
But with this solution you can take current error (X-Frame or 404).

```
iframe.onload = event => {
   const isLoaded = event.target.contentWindow.window.length // 0 or 1
}
```

[MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length)

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**
contentWindow.name will now always throw an error on cross-origin frames.
Seems like the only way is to do this server side (for now).
I have written a small cloudflare worker to capture headers for remote apis and it can be used here to check for X-Frame-Options.

Sample code to check before rendering in iframe: (jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2gud39aw/2/)

```
function checkUrlFrameOptions(apiurl){
  return fetch("https://header-inspector.repalash.workers.dev/?" + new URLSearchParams({
    'apiurl': apiurl,
    'headers': 'x-frame-options'
  }), {
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(r => r.json()).then(json => {
    let xFrameOp = (json.headers['x-frame-options'] || '').toLowerCase();
    // deny all requests
    if(xFrameOp==='deny') return false;
    // deny if different origin
    if(xFrameOp==='sameorigin' && json.origin !== location.origin) return false;
    return true;
  })
}

checkUrlFrameOptions("https://google.com").then((res)=>console.log("google.com can be loaded in iframe: ", res))
checkUrlFrameOptions("https://example.com").then((res)=>console.log("example.com can be loaded in iframe: ", res))
```

The cloudflare worker endpoint ( https://header-inspector.repalash.workers.dev ) is just for testing, don't use this in production. The code is available at: https://gist.github.com/repalash/b1e778dbe3ac2e7149831c530a6535f9
and can be deployed directly as a [cloudflare worker](https://workers.cloudflare.com/)

*OLD Answer*

Here's a simple solution, tested on Chrome and Safari.

```
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
    iframe.onload = function() {
        try {
            iframe.contentWindow.name
        } catch (e) {
            if (e.message.includes('cross-origin')) console.warn(e.message);
            else console.error(e.message);
        }
    }

    iframe.src = "https://google.com";
```

jsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/k5e1mg3t/5/

Comment: Was anyone able to get this to work? I don't see that iframes have a contentWindow.name prop?

Comment: I don't think the fiddles work

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem. I solved it without using onload handler.I was working on AngularJs project so i used $interval and $ timeout. U can also use setTimeout and setInterval.Here's the code:

```
 var stopPolling;
 var doIframePolling;
 $scope.showIframe = true;
 doIframePolling = $interval(function () {
    if(document.getElementById('UrlIframe') && document.getElementById('UrlIframe').contentDocument.head && document.getElementById('UrlIframe').contentDocument.head.innerHTML != ''){
        $interval.cancel(doIframePolling);
        doIframePolling = undefined;
        $timeout.cancel(stopPolling);
        stopPolling = undefined;
        $scope.showIframe = true;
    }
},400);

stopPolling = $timeout(function () {
        $interval.cancel(doIframePolling);
        doIframePolling = undefined;
        $timeout.cancel(stopPolling);
        stopPolling = undefined;
        $scope.showIframe = false;     
},5000);

 $scope.$on("$destroy",function() {
        $timeout.cancel(stopPolling);
        $interval.cancel(doIframePolling);
 });
```

Every 0.4 Seconds keep checking the head of iFrame Document. I somthing is present.Loading was not stopped by CORS as CORS error shows blank page.
If nothing is present after 5 seconds there was some error (Cors policy) etc..
Show suitable message.Thanks. I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: ```Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.``` - are you sure it is working cross-domain?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the accepted answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665488/4038790, you need to check via a server.

Because there's no reliable way to check this in the browser, I suggest you build yourself a quick server endpoint that you can use to check if any url is loadable via iframe. Once your server is up and running, just send a AJAX request to it to check any url by providing the url in the query string as `url` (or whatever your server desires). Here's the server code in NodeJs:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/checkCanLoadIframeUrl', (req, res) => {
  const request = require('request')
  const Q = require('q')

  return Q.Promise((resolve) => {
    const url = decodeURIComponent(req.query.url)

    const deafultTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // Default to false if no response after 10 seconds
      resolve(false)
    }, 10000)

    request({
        url,
        jar: true /** Maintain cookies through redirects */
      })
      .on('response', (remoteRes) => {
        const opts = (remoteRes.headers['x-frame-options'] || '').toLowerCase()
        resolve(!opts || (opts !== 'deny' && opts !== 'sameorigin'))
        clearTimeout(deafultTimeout)
      })
      .on('error', function() {
        resolve(false)
        clearTimeout(deafultTimeout)
      })
  }).then((result) => {
    return res.status(200).json(!!result)
  })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3100)
```