# Detect X-Frame-Options

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is there a way to detect whether or not a page is allowed to load within an iframe?

If a URL can not load within an iframe, I would like to let the user know that the URL they are submitting will not work on our site.

I have tried to get the contents, but that doesn't work:

```
$("iframe#data-url").on("load", function() {
    alert($(this).contents())
});
```

I am not really sure where to go from here.

> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Is there a way to detect `X-Frame-Options`?

Comment: Not sure what the downvoter was upset about, seems like a perfectly valid question to me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because your script and the target URL are on different domains, JavaScript's cross domain policy won't let you access the headers. I ran into the same problem a few months ago and ended up using JavaScript to send an AJAX request to a PHP file which could then parse the headers.

This is what I had in the PHP file. This would then return the result in a JSON array. Let me know if it helps!

```
$error=false;
$urlhere='http://facebook.com';
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => $urlhere,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch);
$headers=substr($response, 0, $httpCode['header_size']);
if(strpos($headers, 'X-Frame-Options: deny')>-1||strpos($headers, 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN')>-1) {
        $error=true;
}
$httpcode= curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
echo json_encode(array('httpcode'=>$httpcode, 'error'=>$error));
```

I know it's not an ideal response but it's all I could get to work with my project.

---

**Edit:** As [Bill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529231/bill-davis) stated below, if you change [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to [`stripos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) you might get better results as it runs a case insensitive search instead.

Comment: This is a decent solution.  JavaScript might not be able to read the headers, but PHP sure can :-)

Comment: Thanks for this! I will also use it for frame breakers such as `if(self!=top)....`

Comment: Great idea, think I'll actually add that into my own code tomorrow!

Comment: Nice. I changed the strpos to stripos for better results

Comment: just one word awesome :)

Comment: Damn, I was to close to doing it in pure ajax. But there's another annoying header in the way `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` that prevents even accessing remote url...