# How to check if website is loadable in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, x-frame-options

I need to check, if website in `iframe` is loaded properly. On my website, users can `POST` custom website, which will show them in iframe. But some websites are protected from insert to iframe (such as google or facebook).

How can I check, if is website loadable in iframe and can be used in iframe?

PS: I haven't show any code, because I have no code and no idea how to do it. (My website runs on Java, so no Apache or PHP).

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21263774/1355315

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect X-Frame-Options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263418/detect-x-frame-options)

Comment: BTW, how can you flag this as duplicate, when I am not running on PHP?

Answer (score 4):

Check HTTP response header for [**X-Frame-Options**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options). Facebook sends X-Frame-Options=DENY, which means "The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so."

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate
>   whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a
>   `<frame>`, `<iframe>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid
>   clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded
>   into other sites.

Check this: [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: No. You need to check the Headers the website sends *you*. You can use [get_headers](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php).

Or do you want javascript? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, that my website runs on Java. I have no Apache or PHP.

Comment: +1. This is a perfectly fit answer to the question. Why the downvote? In fact it is the question which is unclear.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-response-header-in-java/ for Java, or the stackoverflow answer I linked above if you want to do this dynamically in js.

Comment: There's also JS, which is much simpler, that can undo iframes: `if ( location.href != parent.location.href ) { parent.location.href = location.href; }` How do you check for that?

Comment: @abhitalks I didn't downvote... Thanks guys, I will try all possibilities.

Comment: This generally wouldn't work in JavaScript, which is what I think the questioner is actually asking about because the request would probably be denied due to Access Control Allow Origin restrictions. I'm not sure there is a good answer to this question. But this one definitely isn't one.