# detecting "x-frame-options" value using tools?

Tags: header, http-headers, x-frame-options

so first of all, i must say i saw:
[Detect X-Frame-Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263418/detect-x-frame-options)

but i didn't get it, i tried to follow but i don't know how to send AJAX request.

so before i sit down and try to learn how, i was wondering if its possible to check
what the value is by using tools like firebug/burp suite/tamper date etc?

in essence, all im trying to do is be able to go into several webpages (one after another) and being able to tell instantly what the value of X-frame-options is

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Python Code for doing the same

```html
import requests
r = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")
print dict(r.headers).get("x-frame-options")
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can run the following line.

curl -i http://stackoverflow.com/