# How to detect whether a website accepts IFrame embedding using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am writing a [webpage](https://ptc.network/dashboard/test_website/) to test whether any particular website allows embedding into an IFrame.

Webservers use the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header to determine whether or not they allow other websites to embed them using IFrames.

If this header is set to `DENY` or `SAMEORIGIN`, then the embedded IFrame **cannot** load the website.

If a website has `X-Frame-Options` set to either one of these configurations, (such as https://google.com), then I can see this error message in the console:

`Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273042/catch-error-if-iframe-src-fails-to-load-error-refused-to-display-http-ww) is about detecting refused connections in frames (but none of the answers actually work!)

This leads me to my question:

**Is there a way I can detect whether a website allows or denies frames using JQuery?**

Comment: Not a duplicate because I really would like to use JQuery if possible!

Comment: I was not aware that was the case, hence the question :)

Comment: Write a proxy and do `const url ="https://google.com";  $.get("myproxytestifxframe.php", { "site":url},function(res) { if (!res.error) $("iframe").attr("src",url) });`. Here is the code for the proxy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263418/detect-x-frame-options

Comment: Great answer, thanks. This will do just fine

Comment: You can also be one step nastier and do `const url ="https://google.com";   $("iframe").attr("src","myproxyloadpage.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(url)) });`  - but that will likely fail on sites that ajax their content

Comment: That's quite clever