# How to detect X-Frame-Options in an iframe and open link in new tab?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I know this is a popular question, but none of the provided answers seem to be straight forward.

In Pseudocode/Jquery it would be something like:

```
if (X-Frame-Options detected) { 
$('a[target="iframe"]').click(function()) {
$('a[target="_blank"]').show();
})
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I would like to mention that the links are from another domain, so the error is Refused to display 'link' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. The intention is to give to the user a 'Open in new Tab' button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research I found the answer on stackoverflow: [Detect X-Frame-Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263418/detect-x-frame-options?rq=1) and [Catching "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323151/catching-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options?lq=1).

PHP Script:

```
$error=false;
$urlhere=$_GET["url"];
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $urlhere,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch);
$headers=substr($response, 0, $httpCode['header_size']);
if(strpos($headers, 'X-Frame-Options: deny')>-1||strpos($headers, 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN')>-1) {
    $error=true;
}
$httpcode= curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
echo json_encode(array('httpcode'=>$httpcode, 'error'=>$error));
```

AJAX Request:

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $.getJSON("source/script.php?url="+this, function (data) {
     if (data.error) { 
      $('iframe').hide();
      $(".iframe-error").show();
    } else { 
      $(".iframe-error").hide();
      $('iframe]').show();
    }
  });
  });
```

The code to display the iframe and the link to the new tab still needs to be further developed.

Comment: I have experienced the case of the headers sometimes being different (deny vs Deny vs DENY) etc. To get around this I surrounded the `substr` with a quick `strtolower()` and modifying the following conditional to suit