# Load function when iframe unable to load

Tags: iframe

I need to call a function when iframe is unable to load a given specified page.

i don’t have control over the page which i'll be loading in iframe

Is there any way to check when iframe fails to load a page ??

thanks in advance

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273042/catch-error-if-iframe-src-fails-to-load-error-refused-to-display-http-ww