# HTML5 Iframe redirect in case checking connection [ EDIT ]

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, fallback

I have an offline html, and I add an Iframe inside it that redirect to a site if there's connection available. but in case if there's no internet connection the Iframe will redirect to offline page/html.

Can someone explain to me what code that I need to use? I'm using **checking internet connection script** but i don't know what code that I need to insert inside javascript for exchange **alert('You are Online')** > redirect to online site and **alert('You Are Offline')** > redirect to offline page

```js
if(navigator.onLine)
  {
    alert('You are Online');
  }
  else
  {
    alert('You are Offline')
  }
```

```html
<iframe height="500px" width="100%" src="http://example.github.io/" id="foo"></iframe>
<div style="text-align:center"> This Iframe </div>
```

Comment: after end iframe tag you can use noframe tag 
<noframe>this link is not working </noframe>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273042/catch-error-if-iframe-src-fails-to-load-error-refused-to-display-http-ww

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<iframe id="browse" src="" onload="doNothing()" onerror="doRedirect()"></iframe>
```

And in JavaScript

```
function doRedirect(){
    document.getElementById('browse').src = "your offline page";
}
```

or

```
function doRedirect(){
    window.frames['browse'].location.replace("url to offline page");
}
```

Comment: it won't work, after I shut the connection, the Iframe load "Server Not Found" in firefox, not load the offline html/page

Answer (score 0):

Use can using [GlobalEventHandlers.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) for your fallback. For example:

```js
var my_iframe = document.getElementById('my_iframe');

my_iframe.onerror = (my_iframe.src = 'http://example.com');
```

```html
<iframe id="my_iframe" src="http://example.xxx/"></iframe>
```

Or see [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juno_okyo/f99dw1kh/2/).

Comment: How about using "Connection Test" javascript?