# How to check iframe url load server issue in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Can anybody tell how to check  if url is failed to load  in iframe(404,500 etc)  If url is failed  need to hide the iframe and need to display error message to the user.if url is sucess. I want to load url in iframe

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Your question lacks code and detail that you really should know better to provide. For example if the iFrame is from another origin then you cannot interrogate it

Comment: Please have a look here , it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/18552771/4209603