# JAVASCRIPT check if a iframe failed to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap

I am writing a PWA it will load my site as an app on phonegap cordova, my question is how to make a javascript funcion to return a no connection page if it fails to load the iframe and also keep my loader image #loadingMessage intact?

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 
}
#loadingMessage {
background:url(https://i.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.webp) center center no-repeat;
}
</style>

  <iframe style="min-height:100vh" id="frame" src="https://www.test.com" width="100%"  frameBorder="0"></iframe>

<center>
<div id="loadingMessage" class="spinner-border" style="color: #18d26e!important;   
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 45vh;
    bottom: 45vh;
    position: absolute;" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div></center>

<script>
$('#frame').ready(function () {
    //$('#loadingMessage').css('display', 'none');
$("#loadingMessage").fadeOut(3000);
});
$('#frame').load(function () {
   // $('#loadingMessage').css('display', 'none');
$("#loadingMessage").fadeOut(3000);
});
</script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch error if iframe src fails to load . Error :-"Refused to display 'http://www.google.co.in/' in a frame.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273042/catch-error-if-iframe-src-fails-to-load-error-refused-to-display-http-ww)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have connection, your query import will fail as well.

You can fetch a known resource to check for connection and then handle your state according.

The only way to detect iframe states is via [PostMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) api, for that you need to control both the code inside and outside the iframe.

But I think you should load your app directly and not wrap it inside an iframe.

Comment: my query imports and scripts are saved on phone, I just posted this way here, because you guys can see it working, I load it via phone, and than just load the site via iframe, but why should I load it directly via ajax or any other ?method?

Comment: could you give me a `code` example of how to do it using PostMessage api?