# jQuery not working on iframe content

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, input

I am trying to apply css to a label when input fields are focused using jQuery, but it doesn't seem to work. The contact form is loaded inside an iframe. If an iframe is not used, it works fine - check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nN3w2/ (if the iframe doesn't load the server might gone down - but the code is there for you to see).

The iframe and the contact form are located on the same domain. The contact form is included using php to my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#iframe").contents().find("input").focus(function() {
        $("#iframe").contents().find("label").css('opacity','0');
    });
});
</script>
```

non-iframe

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input").focus(function() {
       $("label").css('opacity','0');
    });

    $("input").focusout(function() {
         if($("input").val() ==="" ) {
           $("label").css('opacity','1');
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: works for me when both documents are located on the same domain: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Q7QuW/1/

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5976237/779092
Note: you're going to want to run our code in the iframe's `onload` event, rather than the current document's event.

Comment: I was testing it in jsfiddle with my sites url so that's why it wasn't working. But now it works on my domain, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible

you can't apply jQuery to other domain iframes. It's blocked due to security.

Expanding on "not possible"...

The "[Same origin policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)" apply: your only way of communicating with the contents of iframes that come from another [domain|subdomain|protocol|port] is through the [postMessage API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-document_messaging), which of course requires the other part (the document inside the iframe) to listen to your messages.

**Update after OP's Comment**

Perhaps you can do something like this

```
$('#iframeOne', window.parent.document);
```

Another way to do it

```
window.parent.$("#iframeOne");
```

Another way

```
$("#iframeOne", top.document);
```

If you know the name of the parent window, you can also do

```
$("#iframeOne",opener.document)
```

Here `opener` is the name of the window.

Comment: The iframe is located on my domain though, and so is the contact form php file, I still can't access it?

Comment: I was testing it in jsfiddle with my sites url so that's why it wasn't working. But now it works on my domain, thank you.

Comment: that's what i was thinking that's why i mentioned on the top `you can't apply jQuery to other domain iframes. It's blocked due to security.`